# Will a cyclic heat load transform my martensitic steel? How fast?

Tags: materials, thermodynamics, steel

I have a plunger - that I'm using for glass forming - made out of a martensitic steel. Glass is at 1000°C and since martensite is a metastable phase, should I expect the properties of my plunger to change during its life?

If that's the case how can I calculate how fast it is transforming?

Comment: It depends on the temperature and time the metal is heated , and its original heat-treatment and its chemical composition.